# Linux Kernel Writing

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, file-copying, ext4

How is copying a file in linux different from writing to a file in linux in terms of the functions in kernel they call ?

Does any one of them call `ext4_file_write_iter()` in `fs/ext4/file.c`because `ext4_file_operations` specify it for write operations ?

Comment: I really didn't get your question. Could you add some more details?

Comment: For your second question, you can just search through the tree for that function name and see everywhere it's called (or see what macros resolve to it).

Comment: Userspace does not call kernel filesystem specific functions to write to a file. Userspace programs and libraries use the same syscalls to write to files -- `write()`, `pwrite()`, `writev()` etc. The respective kernel function (that services the syscall) checks the file description the specified file descriptor refers to, and chooses the filesystem-specific function to call (using the generic `struct file_operations` from the `struct file` the file descriptor is associated with).

Comment: Copying a file writes to a file the same way writing to a file writes to a file, unless the copy program is using something like reflink.

Comment: @skrrgwasme yes I used cscope for that but the thing is I want to understand what's actually happenng in the write path like actual block allocation and their parameters so I used printk statements but I am not able to see any of that in syslog once I use cp command.

Comment: Use ftrace with function/function_graph to see it in action... https://lwn.net/Articles/370423/

Comment: The copy program might be using `sendfile()` to transfer file data from one file to the other.